# Can argc overflow?

Tags: c, integer-overflow

I was wandering in SO and saw [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18547114/why-do-we-need-argc-while-there-is-always-a-null-at-the-end-of-argv). Then I started wondering if I can overflow argc.

Standard says that `argv[argc]` must be a null pointer but this will be false if argc overflow.

(I [wrote](https://gist.github.com/boramalper/b0c6116ada4dd8f7e80a) a small C program and a python script to test it but got a `MemoryError`.)

Thanks!

---

> #### [Rationale for International Standard — Programming Languages — C](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/C99RationaleV5.10.pdf) §5.1.2.2.1 *Program startup*
>
> The specification of `argc` and `argv` as arguments to `main` recognizes extensive prior practice. `argv[argc]` is required to be a null pointer to provide a redundant check for the end of the list, also on the basis of common practice.

Comment: `Standard says that argv[argc] must be a null pointer but this will be false if argc overflow`  -- I read this as "Don't let argc overflow." ("Doctor, it hurts when I do this")

Comment: On POSIX and on most Linux systems, the initial stack of `main` -as installed by `execve`-, including its arguments (i.e. `argv`), is much more limited (typically, a few megabytes). So `argc` is less than a few milions and I never heard of an OS where `argc` could be near `INT_MAX`

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: If `int` is 16 bits, it could overflow.

Comment: arguably the implementation will in such case have system specific limit that makes it impossible to pass 2^15 arguments to a program

Comment: Well, I'm certainly not typing them in:)

Comment: How exactly would you pass a number of arguments to a process that would, effectively, exceed the process memory space all by itself, not even counting the executable *taking* those arguments?

Comment: @DevSolar: the quotation is speaking of unusual corner cases, I wouldn't be too surprised if there's an implementation out there where `int` is smaller than the process memory space. Even if there isn't one, it's the kind of hypothetical that the standards folks fret about while considering the rationales for their decisions. After all, they decided not to ban it.

Comment: Hang on a second, what do I mean "I wouldn't be surprised". Any LP64 or LLP64 architecture fits the bill, so Windows or Linux. You'd need a lot of RAM, though. I suppose that if starting from scratch, `argc` should have type `size_t`.

Comment: @SteveJessop: That's what you get for playing it through only for the *old* and *small* architectures. You're right, of course.

Answer (score 78, accepted):

### According to the standard

So, from your quote:

> `argv[argc]` is required to be a null pointer

Therefore, `argc` cannot overflow, because then the above statement would not be true.

### In practice

In practice, the total size of the arguments passed to a program is limited.

On my Linux/x64 system:

```
$ getconf ARG_MAX
2097152
```

Therefore, the total argument size is about 2 megabytes, and `argc` cannot overflow.  I believe this limit measures a combination of the total data in `argv` and the environment.  If you exceed this limit when you try to run a command, `exec()` will fail with `E2BIG`.  From [`man 2 execve`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/execve):

```
E2BIG  The total number of bytes in the environment (envp) and argument
       list (argv) is too large.
```

I believe the ~2 megabyte limit on my system is relatively generous compared to other systems.  My OS X system reports a limit of ~260KB.

### But what if `ARG_MAX` were really big?

Okay, let's suppose you're on an old/weird system, so `int` is 16 bits, and ARG_MAX is well over 2<sup>15</sup>, which is otherwise quite reasonable.  Now, suppose you invoke `execve()` with more than 2<sup>15</sup> arguments.  The implementation has two options.

1. It can allow `argc` to overflow... basically, throwing away your data, ensuring that the program you're running executes in some unexpected and probably erroneous manner, and violating the C standard.  Worst of all, the error is silent, so you might never know.
2. Or, it can simply return `EOVERFLOW` from `execve()`, informing you that it simply can't run an image with that many parameters.  Now, the POSIX / SUS standards don't mention anything about this error result... but, I suspect this is simply because the standard writers never expected `ARG_MAX` to be larger than `INT_MAX`.

Option #2 is the *only* reasonable option.  If your system somehow chooses option #1, then it is *broken* and you should file a bug report.

Alternatively, you could be trying to run an old program compiled for a 16-bit system, but you're running it through some kind of emulator or compatibility layer.  I'd expect that the emulator or compatibility layer would give an error message if you tried to pass more than 2<sup>15</sup> parameters to a program.

Comment: But imagine you are on a system where the ARG_MAX thing is pretty big (for what reasons ever) and it could happen. What kind of failure would it be? As it is still respecting the standard, it can be called C compatible, but it also could occur a undefined behaving, where the programmer has no option to prevent. What kind of error is it?

Comment: I think the Standard has undefined behaviour, there, as signed overflow is not defined.

Comment: @zaibis The requirement for `argv[argc]` to be a null pointer implies a requirement to set `ARG_MAX` small enough that `argc` *cannot* overflow.

Answer (score 17):

In practice, no, you can't. Most systems place a relatively low limit on the total combined size of `argv` and `envp`. Limits in the tens to low hundreds of KB aren't uncommon; see http://www.in-ulm.de/~mascheck/various/argmax/ for a reasonably comprehensive listing of the limits on various OSes.

Comment: That list have no data for Windows but there is [question on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3205027/maximum-length-of-command-line-string) with some numbers.

Answer (score 11):

I tried this:

test.c :

```
 ⚡⚡⚡  more test.c 
#include <stdio.h>
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    printf("argc = %d\n", argc);
    printf("Size of argc = %d\n", sizeof(argc));
    return 0;
}
```

Then used a big zipfile

```
 ⚡⚡⚡  ls -h bigfile 
-rw-r--r-- 1 ehwas ehwas 355M Jan 22 16:54 bigfile
```

Then read the file as parameters to the test program:

```
⚡⚡⚡  ./test $(more bigfile)
```

Result:

```
5 minutes nothing happend, then everything froze
```

Then I tried a smaller file:

```
 ⚡⚡⚡  ls -h notsobigfile 
-rw-r--r-- 1 ehwas ehwas 6.7M Jan 22 17:04 notsobigfile
```

And:

```
 ⚡⚡⚡  ./test $(more notsobigfile)
bash: ./test: Argument list too long
```

Comment: Why use a zip file to generate arguments when you can just $(seq 1 100000)?

Comment: Didn't think of it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

As indicated by the standard, argv[argc] must be a valid value.

So if the run-time environment is in a situation such that it cannot guarantee that, it should not start the program.